# SKK for Kana to Kanji inverter

Tags: docker, kana, kanji

I'm using [kakasi](https://github.com/loretoparisi/kakasi) inverter to convert Kanji characters to Romaji like in the following

```
echo "日本が好きです。" | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka -s -iutf8 -outf8
nippon ga suki desu .
```

KAKASI is a simple **Kanji** to **Kana** inverter based on dictionaries. Doing the opposite it's a pretty hard task, but there are methods to convert **Kana** to **Kanji**, before any conversion to **Romanji**. Kakasi can do **Hiragana** from Kanji, Japanese, etc inversions like

```
echo "7月31日" | iconv -f utf8 -t shift-jis | kakasi -JH -KH -Ea -s | iconv -f shift-jis -t utf8

7 がつ 31 にち
```

I have built [this](https://github.com/loretoparisi/docker/blob/master/libskk/Dockerfile) Dockerfile that comes with both kakasi and **libskk**, that it should be a kana kanji converter, but I cannot get rid of this.
The Dockerfile comes with [this](https://github.com/skk-dev/dict) collection of the SKK dictionaries as well already configured to be used like in the libskk examples [here](https://github.com/ueno/libskk):

```
$ echo "A i SPC" | skk
{ "input": "A i SPC", "output": "", "preedit": "▼愛" }
$ echo "K a p a SPC K a SPC" | skk
{ "input": "K a p a SPC K a SPC", "output": "", "preedit": "▼かぱ【▼蚊】" }
$ echo "r k" | skk -r tutcode
{ "input": "r k", "output": "あ", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "a (usleep 50000) b (usleep 200000)" | skk -r nicola
{ "input": "a (usleep 50000) b (usleep 200000)", "output": "うへ", "preedit": "" }
```

I would like to use `libskk` to invert kana to kanji, eventually using kakasi as intermediate step programmatically. For Kakasi I have build a Node.js wrapper [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/kakasi.js), and I'm trying to do the same with SKK library.

The [current](http://openlab.jp/skk/doc.html) docs is in japanese, while an example doing this is the [mecab-skkserve](http://anti.rosx.net/etc/tools/rome.php), but I do not find and docs about how it works.

Here there are several attempts based on the few `skk` available examples

```
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.L
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.S
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.M
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.M -r tutcode
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "然諾毎度大団", "preedit": "u" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.M -r nicola
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "めく，，つめせうしちきくてたし", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.L.unannotated 
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.itaiji
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
i$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.jinmei 
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.ML
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
$ echo "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u" | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.hukugougo 
{ "input": "n i p p o n g a s u k i d e s u", "output": "にっぽんがすきです", "preedit": "" }
```

And this is a funny pipe between `kakasi` and `skk` passing data with `jq`:

```
echo "もし君を 許せたら" | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka -s -iutf8 -outf8 | awk '{gsub(/./,"& ",$0);print}' | skk -f ../dict/SKK-JISYO.M -r tutcode | jq -r .output
```

where the result will be `養せ校循七野寮` while starting from `もし君を 許せたら`.

**NOTES**

For more info about kakasi see the official web site [here](http://kakasi.namazu.org/index.html.en).

Comment: What's the question? :-)

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer so inverting with skk it seems generates hiragana from romaji (char spaced). Using the option above it generates kanji or a sort of. I’m not sure if this is how it works (doc is japanese) since I cannot get the japanese input sentence.

Comment: You could try Linguistics SE.